# Q - MS Access Assign ID to Matching Items of Large Table

Tags: database, excel, ms-access-2016

I am new to MS Access and I am trying to construct my tables before running my relationships.  My current issue is that I have an asset list of roughly 700,000 with multiple items.  I am trying to assign an item ID so that when researching a replacement cost of one item, it applies it to all of the similar items.

Would this be accomplished with an update query, a filter of some sort or will I have to resort to somehow updating with VBA?  I really just want to update my All Asset Data table with an "Item ID" column that has the auto number.

Also, eventually I am sure my company will update and purchase new gear so eventually there will be new items added to the list (dynamic).  These would need to have ID's added as well.

I come from an excel background and presently I have my "database" in excel with tons of VLOOKUPs and MATCH(INDEX) links.

Comment: Are the items in your asset list unique? If so, you can design your table and add an `Item ID` field with `AutoNumber` datatype, and a unique ID will be automatically assigned to each row of the table.

Comment: No, there is multiple matches of items.  The barcodes are unique and are the primary key.  The past database did not assign this ability.

Comment: If the barcodes are unique and are already the primary key in the table, another `Item ID` field surely isn't required since you can already uniquely identify each item?

Comment: No, so when I lookup, for example "item 1" which is a Item A, "item 2" could also be an Item A.  Presently I have a second table with the columns "ID", "ItemGroup", and "ReplacementCost".  The idea is to find the groups from Table A items, assign them in the second table (Table B) so that when I put a replacement cost in Item A, it applies that cost to all of the Item A's that have unique barcodes.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So I found a tool in Access with the Table Analyzer.  Problem is, I am trying to split the Item to a separate table with a unique ID (exactly what I want), but it puts me over the 2GB limit... so yeah... back where I was.